# Facebook Like Box opacity in IE

Tags: css, facebook, internet-explorer, hover, opacity

I've got a piece of code that's not working properly.
I've got a Facebook widget on my page, that has an opacity of 0.5. When you hover over it, it becomes opacity: 1. In Chrome, Firefox etc. everything works fine. But in IE the hover doesn't do anything.
The widget stays at 0.5 opacity, instead of changing to 1.

I hope somebody can tell me why it's not working and perhaps how to get it working in all browsers.

```
<div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-1" style="width: 33%">
    <div class="art-widget widget widget_text" id="text-2">
        <div class="art-widget-content">
            <div class="textwidget">
                <div class="fb-like-box fb_iframe_widget" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Dansvanopstal" data-width="310" data-height="580" height="580" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=230469016992855&amp;color_scheme=light&amp;header=false&amp;height=580&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDansvanopstal&amp;locale=nl_NL&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_border=false&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=true&amp;width=310"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 310px; height: 580px;"><iframe name="f11894a138" width="310px" height="580px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:like_box Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like_box.php?app_id=230469016992855&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D28%23cb%3Df2d771f9b4%26domain%3Dwww.mijncreaties.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mijncreaties.com%252Ff1d810dd4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;color_scheme=light&amp;header=false&amp;height=580&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDansvanopstal&amp;locale=nl_NL&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_border=false&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=true&amp;width=310" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 310px; height: 580px;" class=""></iframe></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.layout-item-1{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.layout-item-1:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

So in a nutshell:
When you visit the page in Chrome, Firefox etc. the Facebook widget shows 0.5 opacity, but when you hover over it, it turns to 1 opacity (making it fully visible).
But when you visit the page in IE, the Facebook widget shows 0.5 opacity, and when you hover over it nothing happens. It just remains 0.5. It should change to 1.

When you hover just next to the Facebook DIV, on the edge (the 5 pixels between the edge of the first DIV and the Facebook DIV), it does work.

See it at the bottom of the page: http://bit.ly/1lMOcMu

Answer (score 0):

Opacity setup for Internet Explorer:

```
/* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Comment: It's not about the opacity. That works fine. It's about the hover effect not working properly.